# Install vs_ajax Extenstion in Magento it will display fatal error

Tags: extensions, magento-1

When click on to add to cart in Magento theme it will display error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in
>   ..\app\code\community\VS\Ajax\controllers\IndexController.php on line
>   55

```
public function addAction()
{
    $cart   = $this->_getCart();
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    if($params['isAjax'] == 1){
        $response = array();
        try {
            if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode())
                );
                $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
            }

            $product = $this->_initProduct();
            $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');

            /**
             * Check product availability
             */
            if (!$product) {
                $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
                $response['message'] = $this->__('Unable to find Product ID');
            }

            $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            if (!empty($related)) {
                $cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
            }

            $cart->save();

            $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);

            /**
             * @todo remove wishlist observer processAddToCart
             */
            Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
            array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
            );

            if (!$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()){
                $message = $this->__('%s was added to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($product->getName()));
                $response['status'] = 'SUCCESS';
                $response['message'] = $message;
                //New Code Here
                $this->loadLayout();
            //  $toplink = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('top.links')->toHtml();

                $sidebar_block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('cart_sidebar');
                Mage::register('referrer_url', $this->_getRefererUrl());
                $sidebar = $sidebar_block->toHtml();
                $response['toplink'] = $toplink;
                $response['sidebar'] = $sidebar;
            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $msg = "";
            if ($this->_getSession()->getUseNotice(true)) {
                $msg = $e->getMessage();
            } else {
                $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
                foreach ($messages as $message) {
                    $msg .= $message.'<br/>';
                }
            }

            $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
            $response['message'] = $msg;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
            $response['message'] = $this->__('Cannot add the item to shopping cart.');
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response));
        return;
    }else{
        return parent::addAction();
    }
}
```

Comment: put your IndexController.php code....

Comment: I Am Install Vs_Ajax Extestion just installed. I give link of this extensions.[extenstion link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/vs-ajax-add-to-cart-add-to-wishlist-add-to-compare-paging-toolbar.html)

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Answer (score 1):

This error is occurring because `cart_sidebar` does not exist in the layout for that page.  (You can confirm this by checking the value of the `$sidebar_block` variable.)

You'll either need to re-add the block, or modify the extension to not reference it.